# Showing 1 to 10 of 35 entries not working in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, dynamic-data-display

I'm working with laravel 5.6 showing data, but it's not working perfectly.

This code displayed me in fist page Showing 0 to 10 of 35 and last page displayed Showing 30 to 40 of 35

```
$page    = $request->has('page') ? $request->get('page') : 1;
$total   = UserAdmin::count();
$perPage = 10;
$showingTotal  = $page * $perPage;

$currentShowing = $showingTotal>$total ? $total : $showingTotal;
$showingStarted = $showingTotal - $perPage;
$tableInfo = "Showing $showingStarted to $showingTotal of $total";
```

I want to Showing 1 to 10 of 35 entries in first page and last page will be display Showing 30 to 35 of 35 entries

Comment: use paginate : https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/pagination

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: I want to Showing 1 to 10 of 35 entries in first page and last page will be display Showing 30 to 35 of 35 entries. But it displayed Showing 0 to 10 of 35 and last page displayed Showing 30 to 40 of 35 @Matadeleo

Comment: You're expectation is incorrect. The last page should display 31 to 35. (Each page range would be 1 to 10, 11 to 20, 21 to 30, 31 to 35)

Comment: Yeah, my expectation is incorrect. I understand my problem. please can you help me how to displayed this 1 to 10, 11 to 20, 21 to 30, 31 to 35. @RichardAtHome

Comment: $firstNumber = $currentPage * $pageSize - ($pageSize - 1);
$lastNumber = $currentPage * $pageSize;
if ($lastNumber > $totalNumber) {$lastNumber = $totalNumber; }

echo "Showing $startNumber to $lastNumber of $totalNumber;

(typed into SO without testing, but you get the idea) :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$tableInfo = "Showing $showingStarted to $currentShowing of $total";
```

Use specified $showingTotal instead of $currentShowing

Answer (score 3):

why so complex logic when it can be obtain by direct object members `$shops->firstItem()` and `$shops->lastItem()`

Also, in case of total 9 records it will show wrong in last page Showing 6 to 10 of total 9 entries

example:
Showing `{{ $shops->firstItem() }}` to `{{ $shops->lastItem() }}`
of total `{{$shops->total()}}` entries

Answer (score 1):

you should try this:

Please use paginate in your query and try like:

```
$perPage = 10;

$rsltUsers   = UserAdmin::paginate($perPage);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because your `$showingTotal` is a fixed value, calculated from `$page * $perPage`.

A quick and dirty solution would be to add a line:

```
if ($showingTotal > $total) {
    $showingTotal = $total;
}
```

But please, consider using the proper paginate offered in Laravel. The `$showingTotal` should be dynamically updated, not simply calculated from fixed variables.